# Why can't the overload operator<() implement the comparison function?

Tags: c++

I was looking at this. The author first defined `operator<()` in my_data and said "everything is normal". After adding a member variable, he said "operator<() does not really implement a comparison operation".
I want to know what is the difference between the two and why the former is wrong?

```cpp
struct my_data
{
    std::string key;
    std::string value;
    //first
    bool operator<(const my_data data)const {           
        return key < data.key;
    }
};
//second
struct Compare
{
    bool operator()(const my_data& l, const my_data& r)
        const {
        return l.key < r.key;
    }
};
```

from [there](https://youtu.be/sbiF1HDcG7U?list=PLs3KjaCtOwSZ2tbuV1hx8Xz-rFZTan2J1&t=132)

Comment: missing reference for `my_data::operator<`

Comment: *"After adding a member variable"* Which one? Seems unrelated to `Compare`...

Comment: The presenter is arguing that maybe `my_data` may not be meaningfully compared with other `my_data` but they still want it to be sortable for the purpose of storing them in a set. So they decided to use an external comparator instead of intrusively changing `my_data`. Whether or not it makes sense to make a type comparable depends on the application and what that type represents. Both solutions would work though.

Comment: @Jarod42     std::string value;

Comment: The literal answer to the title is "*it can*, but the author thinks *it shouldn't*"

Comment: It seems that "the author" is confusing "comparing" with "ordering".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With

```
struct my_data
{
    std::string key;
    std::string value;
    //first
    bool operator<(const my_data data)const {           
        return key < data.key;
    }
};

std::set<my_data> data;
```

You can use the class with a `std::set`, but your `operator <` isn't using all of the object, it is just comparing a single field.  That is what the author of the video is complaining about.  They take issue that it only compares one field of the object, and not the whole state of the object.  By switching to

```
struct my_data
{
    std::string key;
    std::string value;
};

struct Compare
{
    bool operator()(const my_data& l, const my_data& r)
        const {
        return l.key < r.key;
    }
};

std::set<my_data, Compare> data;
```

There is no longer a "lying" `operator <`, but instead a custom comparator that compares just what you want.

Comment: The member operator in `struct my_data` compares the variable `key`.  The external operator in `struct Compare` compares the variable `key` in the two `my_data` structures.  How is the first one not comparing "just what you want"?

Comment: @TRPh They are both comparing "just what you want", and that is the issue the video author has.  They believe that that member `operator <` should compare all of the members of the object, not "just what you want".

Comment: @TRPh -- you're right that they do exactly the same thing. The issue isn't about **what** they do, it's about what **they announce** that they do. The argument is that **naming** this comparison `operator<` is misleading, because it doesn't mean anything to say that one `my_data` object is **less than** another `my_data` object. So instead of using `operator<`, the author prefers something called `Compare`, because that doesn't have the implications that `<` has; it's okay with him to say "this `set` object **compares** elements with `Compare`".

Comment: @PeteBecker To further explain it, you might think of a `Student` class that has a `ID` member. In this particular set, it makes sense to order the set based on each students' id, however a student with an `id=0` isn't actually less than a student with an `id=999`. And if you actually create an `operator<` in `Student`, then you are implying student with `id=0` is less than another student with `id=999`.